# How to customize the position of the inpage link from <a href="#link"> with respect to the top of the page after clicking?

Tags: jquery, css, position, height, href

css I used for header to make it fixed

```
.site-header {
 position: fixed;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:1020px;
    top:-20px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

I have the body parts which contains two divs

This is in left side

```
<div id="sidebar" style="float:left" class="affix-top">
<div id="nav-anchor"></div>
<nav class="indexnav">
<ul id="indexlist">
<li id="one"><a href="#AdolescentGynecology">Adolescent gynecology</a></li>
<li><a href="#BreastEvaluation">Breast evaluation</a></li>
<li><a href="#BirthControl">Birth control/emergency contraception</a></li>

</ul>
</nav></div>
```

This is in right side

```
    <div id="indexcontent">
<section id="AdolescentGynecology" tabindex="-1">
                <span class="indexcontent-title">Adolescent gynecology</span><p></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce placerat est egestas, pretium tellus id, egestas mauris. Vestibulum porttitor, massa tristique sodales rutrum, ex elit pulvinar urna, at suscipit quam arcu a turpis. Suspendisse ut hendrerit ligula. Mauris at diam accumsan, mollis risus a, venenatis magna. Phasellus sem arcu, lobortis id sapien quis, fringilla faucibus nulla. Ut fermentum gravida sem non malesuada. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce ullamcorper elit at ornare lacinia. Curabitur sed feugiat magna. Nulla quis libero dignissim, maximus leo consectetur, laoreet massa. Maecenas et malesuada lacus. Morbi at condimentum ipsum. Morbi suscipit leo eros, vel hendrerit felis molestie nec. In nec maximus est.</p>
</section>
<section id="BreastEvaluation" tabindex="-1">
            <span class="indexcontent-title">Breast evaluation</span><p></p>
<p>Vivamus vitae quam ut nulla gravida sollicitudin. Integer congue mauris lectus, cursus ornare nulla scelerisque in. Suspendisse consectetur egestas pellentesque. Maecenas vulputate elit quis nunc iaculis, in malesuada nulla condimentum. Maecenas auctor quam libero, a condimentum purus eleifend ac. Donec vestibulum lectus quis risus condimentum suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam libero leo, molestie vel purus non, semper sagittis mi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mi orci, aliquam sed velit non, vulputate scelerisque metus. Sed vel libero quis nibh placerat bibendum.</p>
</section>
<section id="BirthControl">
             <span class="indexcontent-title">Birth control/emergency contraception</span><p></p>
<p>Vivamus vitae quam ut nulla gravida sollicitudin. Integer congue mauris lectus, cursus ornare nulla scelerisque in. Suspendisse consectetur egestas pellentesque. Maecenas vulputate elit quis nunc iaculis, in malesuada nulla condimentum. Maecenas auctor quam libero, a condimentum purus eleifend ac. Donec vestibulum lectus quis risus condimentum suscipit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam libero leo, molestie vel purus non, semper sagittis mi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mi orci, aliquam sed velit non, vulputate scelerisque metus. Sed vel libero quis nibh placerat bibendum.</p>
</section>
```

Now, when I make a click on one of the

elements in the div id="sidebar" it should navigate to the href location. Here, in case of loading the referenced element to the top of the window. I need to load to a given height in the browser. How do I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your fixed position header is overlapping the top part of your div.content2. I noted there was a typo in the css for .content1, I assume you meant `float:left` not `float;left`.

To position each section just below the header, instead of at the top of the page where the header obscures part of it, you could set the scrollTop of the page to the vertical offset of the section with respect to div.content2 minus the height of the header.  This is easily handled with a click handler.

```
//set the page scrollTop so the selected element appears just
//below the bottom of the fixed header
function scrollTo(contentEl) {

    //assume the href of the anchor is '#id'
    var el = $(contentEl.attr("href"));

    //don't do anything if the ID isn't found
    if (el.length > 0) {

      //height of the header may change if the window is resized
      //so recheck it with each scrollTo call
      var HeaderHeight = $(".header")[0].clientHeight;

      //set the top margin on content2 so the first element
      //displays properly on page load
      $(".content2").css({"margin-top":HeaderHeight+"px"});

      var pos = el.position();
      var newtop = pos.top - HeaderHeight;

      //scrolling above the top is probably silly  
      if (newtop < 0) newtop = 0;

        console.log($(".content2").position().top+ ". "+el.attr("id")+ ": "+$("html").scrollTop()+" - "+pos.top+" - "+newtop);
      $("html").scrollTop(newtop)

      //return false to cancel the href if we scrolled
      return(false);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".content1").affix();

    //use scrollTo to handle click events on nav anchors
    $(".content1 ul").on("click","a",function(){return scrollTo($(this))})

    //set top margin of .content2 so first element appears below the header
    $(".content2").css({"margin-top":$(".header")[0].clientHeight+"px"})

});
```

Update [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pz1a3z2u/100/)